# Node.js HTTP Server- Taking long time to load and is not sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpmodule

I am learning node.js, While using HTTP module i tried to create by own server as per instruction of video tutor but my server is not sending any response at port 3000 and port 8000.

*

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { 
    if(req === '/'){ 
        res.write('Hello world, first program in server using http module');
        res.end();
    }
    if(req === '/api/courses'){
        res.write(json.strigify([1,2,3]));
        res.end();
    }
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening @port 8000');
```

*

Comment: Output of above program: PS D:\Programming note-self\projects> node app.js
Listening @port 8000

Comment: Did the video tutor instruct you to make the strict comparison `req === '/'`? Look up some examples of `createServer` usage online and see how they check which route the request is coming through.

Comment: Yes, he instructed to make strict comparison, but i think i found the mistake, I just forgot to use url properties of req method while comparing and now issue is solved. Thank you for your advice. using req.url === '/' helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict comparison `req === '/'` is comparing a *request object* with a string, a comparison which will never be true.

You likely meant to use: `req.url === '/'`